Isaiah 62:11(c)'s use of the phrase "His recompense/work before Him"
I hope I am Not making much ado about nothing.

Isaiah 62:11
New American Standard Bible 1995
11 (a) Behold, the Lord has proclaimed to the end of the earth, (b)
Say to the daughter of Zion, “Lo, your salvation comes; (c) Behold His
reward is with Him, and His recompense before Him.”


Isaiah 62:11
English Standard Version
11 (a) Behold, the Lord has proclaimed
to the end of the earth: (b) Say to the daughter of Zion,
“Behold, your salvation comes; (c) behold, his reward is with him,
and his recompense before him.”


Isaiah 62:11
New King James Version
11 (a) Indeed the Lord has proclaimed To the end of the world: (b)
“Say to the daughter of Zion, ‘Surely your salvation is coming; (c)
Behold, His reward is with Him, And His work before Him.’ ”


62:11
The Westminster Leningrad Codex
11 הִנֵּ֣ה יְהוָ֗ה הִשְׁמִ֙יעַ֙
אֶל־קְצֵ֣ה הָאָ֔רֶץ אִמְרוּ֙ לְבַת־צִיּ֔וֹן הִנֵּ֥ה יִשְׁעֵ֖ךְ בָּ֑א
הִנֵּ֤ה שְׂכָרוֹ֙ אִתּ֔וֹ וּפְעֻלָּת֖וֹ לְפָנָֽיו׃

For the most part Isaiah 62:11 is an encouraging and uplifting verse for the Israelites.
As one reads on to Isaiah 62:11(c), the phrase "His reward is with Him" seems quite straightforward to understand.  Essentially, said phrase is suggesting that
The Messiah, Jesus Christ, will bring with him Salvation, Redemption, Liberation, Love, Joy, Peace, etc. to the Israelites.
However, subsequently, the phrase "His recompense/work before Him" got my attention, and I would like to get a deeper contextual understanding of the use of "recompense/work" words.

( https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/recompense )
Webster definition for Recompense transitive verb
1a : to give something to by way of compensation (as for a service
rendered or damage incurred) b: to pay for 2: to return in kind :
requite
recompense
2 of 2 noun : an equivalent or a return for something done, suffered,
or given : compensation

Recompense seems to indicate that Jesus Christ will
i) compensate for those who suffered loss, injury, etc.
ii) discipline the wicked which is a manifestation of His Justice prevailing
However, it's kind of strange that the NKJV uses the word "work" which is Overly Broad which does seems Unsuitable.
In any case, could someone please respond by deeper contextual explanation for Isaiah 62:11(c)'s use of the phrase "His recompense/work before Him"? (Please also consider the Hebrew in the response if one knows Hebrew well)

"Much ado about nothing" [much] is much observed on here! Many thrive on that, here, in Hermeneutics! Especially if the details and minutia turn out to be significant. As they often do. So, ask away!

The Hebrew word used is פעלה "pe'ullah". It is simply the passive participle (pluralised) of the verb "to do" or "to act" or "to work". So it literally means "works" or "deeds" or "labours". However it also takes on a secondary meaning of the wages or recompense that someone is given for their labour.
Think of it this way; "overtime" is just the extra time spent working, but people  also use it to refer to their extra wages.
"I need to check my bank account and see if I got my overtime"
Anyway, this means that it is quite ambiguous. It could simply mean wages or recompense, and thus be a synonym for the word translated as ""reward" in the preceeding clause; or it could be the that God's work or deed which is before him (literally before his face), refers to the restoration of Jerusalem which is mentioned in verse 1 of the same chapter.
That is, God has not forgotten the sufferings of his redeemed people in the restored city of Jerusalem, but they are his work, and are ever before his face, and he is coming to reward them.

Welcome to the site, Louis, and for a helpful answer. Hope you contribute again.

Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics SE Louis. +1. We are glad you are here. Please take a moment to take the site tour and check out what we are looking for in answers and the FAQs. We're passionate about high quality answers. Also consider going through the Help Center's sections on asking and answering questions.

עבד also means work (not used here) but also implies servant.  Thus, פעל is more appropriate for God's work.  Unlike Greek, Hebrew words often have a simple basic meaning that the specific meaning depends on the context. Note the varied meanings in the lexicon.

פְּעֻלָּה: פעל (...),... work, deed (...).
—1. of people: —a. work, labour Jr 31:16 2C 15:7; —b. action Ps 17:4 pl.; —c. wage (i.e. the proceeds of (or the reward for) labour, cf. עָמָל as in Qoh 1:3) Lv 19:13 (פְּעֻלַּת שָׂכִיר), Ezk 29:20 (Zimmerli Ezechiel 717), Pr 10:16 (parallel with תְּבוּאָה), 11:18 (פְּעֻלַּת־שָֽׁקֶר).
—2. of God: —a. action Ps 28:5 pl.; —b. reward Is 40:10 (parallel with שָׂכָר), 49:4 61:8 62:11 (parallel with שָׂכָר); —c. punishment Is 65:7 Ps 109:20. †
--
Koehler, L., Baumgartner, W., Richardson, M. E. J., & Stamm, J. J. (1994–2000). In The Hebrew and Aramaic lexicon of the Old Testament (electronic ed., p. 951). E.J. Brill.

עשה is a more common word for do.
How פעל is translated varies with different translations it might help to see how Isaiah used the word.  He used in the same form of the word five times: 40:10; 49:4; 61:8; 62:11; 65:7.
